# Adding Sliders To Blog Posts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

`I` have found a JsFiddle similar to what I'm talking about, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vrh9/353/) to see it. I'm trying to add something similar to this on my site, but instead of the links that causes the posts to slide I would like an arrow. Another arrow would have to appear to back to the previous blog post if the arrow to go to the next post is clicked. I don't know where to start programming this. Does anyone know if I could just remove the links and turn them into arrows with just pure CSS?

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if I could just remove the links and turn them into arrows with just pure CSS?

Yes you can.

**Edit** You can refer to this fiddle for two options on making arrows, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xJ9mC/).

Here is how you make a css triangle,

```
a.btnL {
    border-right: 20px solid brown;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    display: inline-block; /* not needed but block is */
}
```

If you only want 2 triangles then you will need to rewrite your script due to how it is functioning.

Here is an updated fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3Vrh9/354/)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

html:

```
<div class="post-container">
    <a href="#" class="arrow left"></a>
    <a href="#" class="arrow right"></a>
    <!-- Your post -->
</div>
```

css:

```
.post-container {
    position: relative;
}

.arrow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
}

.left {
    border-right: 20px solid blue;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    left: -15px;
    width: 0;
}

.right {
    border-left: 20px solid blue;
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    right: 15px;
    width: 0;
}
```

And a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/kYH6S/1/